# Spring attach data to the current transaction

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Is there a way to access the current transaction in Spring ? My objective is to the add some information to the transaction when it starts and use that information in all method calls within the same transaction.

Here is a solution with EJB: [How can i attach data to a JTA transaction? (or uniquely identify it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853347/how-can-i-attach-data-to-a-jta-transaction-or-uniquely-identify-it) I am looking for the same with spring.

Comment: use @Inject in you service classes to inject the transaction.

Comment: Read it here [Accessing current transaction in Spring](http://wordgraphs.com/post/3916/Accessing-current-transaction-in-Spring)

Comment: Read this section [Understanding the Spring Framework transaction abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic-ptm)

Comment: @Braj but that does not indicate how to add objects to the transaction.

Comment: But it answers your first question `Is there a way to access the current transaction in Spring ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach data to the thread using a `ThreadLocal`, and then use a `TransactionSynchronizationManager` to clear the `ThreadLocal`, effectively creating a transaction scoped variable:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(
    new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void afterCompletion() {
            ... clear the ThreadLocal ...
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I don't want to attach data to all the thread but only to the transaction. in EJB in the link I mentioned we can use SessionSynchronization to attach objects to current transaction, does the TransactionSynchronizationManager plays the same role and how ?

Comment: it plays the same role, the call to `registerSynchronization` adds the `TransactionSynchronizationAdapter` to a list of callback that get executed at different points in the transaction lifecycle, in this case after commit OR rollback. by storing the variables on the thread and clearing the thread variable it at the next commit, that makes the variable effectively transaction scoped

Comment: So you say that at in one thread there is only one transaction at a time ? And one transaction can't be shared to another thread ?

Comment: that is correct, unless you are not using the most common transaction managers such as JpaTransactionManager or HibernateTransactionManager. also there could be nested transactions but that is also an unusual case. currently in the very large majority of Spring applications those two statements are true